# Why is Adobe Lightroom 6 incompatible with the upcoming macOS 10.15 (Catalina)?

Tags: macos, adobe-lightroom

I receive a system warning that Adobe Lightroom 6.14 (perpetual license) is incompatible with future versions of macOS when starting it under macOS Mojave. Lightroom 6 is a 64 bit application, so where is the incompatibility?

Comment: Could you attach or elaborate on the warning? Was it an email from the vendor? A post here or elsewhere? Something that Adobe sent you or programmed into the application? If you could edit that in the body, that's ideal - but you don't have to make a change - someone might know exactly what you are asking and have an answer. (or you'll get people guessing on some or all of the above)

Comment: @bmike You are right. It is a system warning from macOS.

Comment: Did you find a solution how to re-install LR 6 ?

Answer (score 4):

Catalina drops support for more than just 32bit apps. Kernel Extensions are no longer supported for example. If Lightroom uses a kext, this will not work. Catalina also runs the system from a read only volume. If Lightroom requires modifying any of these folders, then you're out of luck.

However, I don't believe the above is the cause. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Lightroom 6 (what you're using) is Lightroom CC (2015) or earlier right? If that's the case, the last time I used Lightroom CC (2015) the main app is 64bit but parts of the app are 32bit. A quick search online suggests that the parts in LR that are 32bit include Adobe QT32 Server and dynamiclinkmanager.

I've not tested it, but I suppose there is a small chance that the app could run without these 32bit components. Maybe I should stop speculating.

Comment: It is Adobe Lightroom 6.14, the last version with a perpetual license.

Comment: I think you're on to something - I would expect an SDK / API or some library within the app is still 32bit. Even if a program itself is 64 bit - that does not mean all the libraries, helpers, updater app and utility apps are updated. All of those would need an update if they are now deprecated on the OS side or the OS dependancies are going to change or not ship.

Comment: The licence manager and AAM may also be 32-bit in older pre-CC software.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Catalina beta 3 and my Lightroom 5.7.1 works perfectly. No change in the transition from Mojave. In fact, I received annoying messages in the past (when in Mojave) about the future incompatibility of the software; well, these messages are gone now.

So I would say Lightroom 6 should work.

Answer (score 2):

LR 6 and 5 are not compatible due to the installer that is 32 bit.  Even Adobe indicates that previously installed versions will likely continue to work.  But you will not be able to install on a fresh install.  Perhaps the installation steps can be replicated, the activation would probably be the most complex.

> Older versions use 32-bit licensing components and installers. Therefore, they cannot be installed and activated after upgrading to macOS Catalina. Upgrading to macOS Catalina with an older version already installed on your computer may allow the application to function in some capacity; however, you will not be able to reinstall or activate the application after the macOS upgrade.

https://helpx.adobe.com/sg/photoshop/kb/photoshop-and-macos-catalina.html

Comment: I arrive to this conclusion when I did a "repair" of my Lightroom and it un-installed it. Now Adobe does not provide the download of the installer nor any alternative to install on modern OS. I found that situation quite negative as I bought a perpetual license exactly because I did not want a monthly subscription but I cannot use anymore. If Adobe cannot resolve this, I will switch to another company (e.g. Dxo)

Comment: Instructions that can be followed before uninstalling, making it possible to reinstall: https://github.com/krema/lightroom6-on-macOS-64bit
Perhaps you can still manage basis an old backup?